# Querying for a key in DynamoDB with a fallback to a default value

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

There is a table in DynamoDB `books`, no indices, just a partition key `book_id`. There is also a "default" book that has an id `default`. Is it possible to query for a specific book OR for a default one? Kind of having a fallback. I am want to use it in combination with API Gateway.

```
{
    "TableName": "books",
    "KeyConditionExpression": "book_id = :v1 or book_id = :v2",
    "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
        ":v1": {
            "S": "12345"
        },
        ":v2": {
            "S": "default"
        }
    }
}
```

I get `"Invalid operator used in KeyConditionExpression: OR"`. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that in `KeyConditionExpression` which supports only direct partition key comparison and optional second condition for sort key where both of these condition (if the second is provided) must be true. In other words, you can only use `and` operator and the second condition must be based on a sort key, not on the partition key.

What you can do is to run the query to look for a book with a given book_id, if there is no such book, query will return empty result. Then you can either run another query to look for the default book and return it instead, or ,more preferably, you can precache that default book and return it without performing another query. Of course, this depends on how often you want to change the default book, if ever.

So in pseudo-code it might look like

```
result = query(book_id)

if (result is empty) {
  result = cached_result || query(default_book_id)
}

return result
```